# jQuery - add/remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I have the following problem on hand:
Create two buttons that will show/hide corresponding content underneath.
I achieved it using this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $(".content1").hide();
    $(".content2").show();
  });
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $(".content1").show();
    $(".content2").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.content1 {
  display: none;
}

.frequency {
  display: flex;
}

.frequency button {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.frequency>button:hover,
.frequency>button.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frequency">
  <button id="button1">button1text</button>
  <button id="button2">button2text</button>
</div>
<div class="content1">text1</div>
<div class="content2">text2</div>
```

To take this one step further, I would like the last button that was clicked to stay highlighted (red). I tried playing with addClass, but the code got very messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/shree/8jdow2s4/5/

Comment: I think you should do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oh4rsc2g/)

Comment: Yep, you've both shown exactly what I needed. Thanks, I feel like a potato now.

Answer (score 0):

in case that more buttons might be added in the future, you can use this solution
it'll work for multiple contents without editing your script.

just link your button with `content-index` attribute
then this index with your tab using `index` attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-content').click(function() {

    // get selected tab index
    const contentIndex = $(this).attr('content-index')

    // remove active class from content
    $('.content').removeClass('active')

    // add active class to selcted content
    $('[index=' + contentIndex + ']').addClass('active')

    // remove active class from all buttons
    $('.toggle-content').removeClass('active')

    // add active class to selcted button
    $(this).addClass('active')

  })

});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.active {
  display: block;
}

.frequency {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px
}

.frequency button {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.frequency>button:hover,
.frequency>button.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frequency">
  <button class='toggle-content' content-index='1'>button1text</button>
  <button class='toggle-content active' content-index='2'>button2text</button>
  <button class='toggle-content' content-index='3'>button3text</button>
</div>
<div class="content" index='1'>text1</div>
<div class="content active" index='2'>text2</div>
<div class="content" index='3'>text3</div>
```